# Are fields $B_{\mu}$, $W_{\mu}$ only before electroweak symmetry breaking (EWSB), and $\gamma$, $Z$, $W^{\pm}$ after it?

Tags: standard-model, symmetry-breaking, electroweak

In the context of Lagrangian of Standard Model of particle physics, is the usage of the notation with $B_{\mu}$ and $W_{\mu}$ *before* electroweak symmetry breaking (EWSB), and the notation with $\gamma$, $Z$, $W^{\pm}$ *after* electroweak symmetry breaking?

Or is the notation *independent* to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use whatever notation / representation for the fields you want to; physics can't depend on your choice of variables. But yes $B_\mu$ and $W_\mu$ are more useful variables for describing the Standard Model when the Higgs vev is zero, and $\gamma, Z, W^{\pm}$ are more useful when the Higgs vev takes its present-day value.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation.

Comment: @Andrew sorry for the trivial question. Did you use the expression "higgs vev zero/not zero" rather than "symmetry breaking" because of this https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/439384/226902 ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian As far as I'm concerned, "electroweak symmetry breaking" is equivalent to "Higgs vev is nonzero." Although, your linked answer is correct, that you can't really spontaneously break a gauge symmetry, so "spontaneous symmetry breaking" is a misnomer for describing what happens in the electroweak sector, even though that's the standard terminology.